# ¿Cómo crear un excel (.xlsx) desde Genexus ? utilito .Net

Tags: excel, .net, genexus

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2476,ExcelDocument+data+type

Según en la documentación hay que descargar unos .DLL pero no logro comprender como y donde dejar dichos dll tambien dice que si es para java o Net son dll diferentes en este caso uso .net.

También hay un ejemplo pero claro al pegarlo y cambiarles  los datos no logra generar un excel solo columnas vacias si lo ejecutas desde un webpanel desde los eventos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La eppplus.dll se distribuye con Genexus, deberia estar en el bin de Net (Ejemplo: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17U8\gxnet\bin)
Por lo que dices la planilla se genera pero vacia, si logra crearse el problema no es por la DLL, de pronto es por los datos que accedes.
De pronto es bueno que incluyas el código que programaste en este post o incluso poner valores "harcoded" del tipo:

```
&ExcelDocument.Cells(1, 1).Number = 50
```

Con eso deberia queda en la fila 1, columna 1 el valor 50.